# How to include a Set statement in tMSSQLOutput block

Tags: sql-server, talend

I have integrated with a SQL Server database using Talened. The jobs insert, update and delete records along with many reads.

Recently, the ERP using this database was upgraded and now we have to run a Set statement before executing any queries in order to perform the transactions.

The Set statement looks like this:

```
Set Contact_Info [binary value]
```

I cannot figure out a way to do this in Talend. Doesn't seem to be possible in a `tMSSQLOutput` block. Any suggestions?

Comment: I always use a connection component, which in your case is a solution as well: Connection -> Row -> output. This way you can run that set command in your transaction / session.

Comment: Apologies for being a little slow on this one...  By Connection, you mean tMSSQLConnection?  What's the Row?

Comment: Kindly provides some sample design of your job, which would help us to understand your problem much better.

Comment: tMSSQLConnection -> tMSSQLRow (here you'll include the SET) -> [.. tMsSQLOuutput]

Answer (score 0):

The components `tMSSqlOutput` and `tMSSqlInput` are not designed to set properties or execute commands, You to use the [tMSSqlRow](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tMSSqlRow) component to execute such command.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Balazs' approach and it worked perfectly. I added a connection block and the row block. I set the row block and my update/insert block to both use the connection block. The connection is also set to autocommit. Worked like a charm.